# How to remove part of URL with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to remove part of URL onload with Javascript but I have a problem.

My code is like this

```js
$('.leg').attr('href', function(_, href) {
  return href.replace('/en/', '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="leg">
    <a href="https://example.com/en/somefile.doc">Download</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I’m trying is to remove /en/ on load from URL. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: The `.leg` element is the `li` and doesn't have a `href`. You want `$('.leg a')`. Also note that you want to use `.replace('/en/', '/')` otherwise you remove all `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to keep one forward slash `/` when replacing `/en/`. Also I assume you want to change href of `a` and not `.leg`.

```
$('.leg a').attr('href', function(_, href) {
  return href.replace('/en', '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the href and replace parts with

`var newLink = link.getAttribute("href").replace('/en/', '');`

```js
function changeLink() {     
  var link = document.getElementById("mylink");
  var newLink = link.getAttribute("href").replace('/en/', '/');
  link.setAttribute('href', newLink);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="leg">
    <a id="mylink" href="https://example.com/en/somefile.doc">Download</a>
    <button onClick="changeLink()">Change link</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
$('.leg').attr('href', function(_, href) {
  return href.replace('en/', '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li >
    <a class="leg" href="https://example.com/en/somefile.doc">Download</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify replace as below:

```
<script>
$('.leg a').attr('href', function(_, href) {
  return href.replace('/en/', '/');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the href attribute from anchor tag not from leg class leg element. 
1)Remove class ="leg" from li and put it in a herf.

```
<li>
   <a  class="leg" href="https://example.com/en/somefile.doc">Download
   </a>
</li>

$('.leg').attr('href', function(_, href) {
    return href.replace('/en','');
});
```

or Change the jquery select to select the a tag to. `$('.leg  a').attr(...`

https://jsfiddle.net/pnwdh5tk/